# Can't associate post to Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having extreme difficulty associating post to a user registered in devise.

I generated a post scaffold and got everything set up correctly in Devise.
I added a migration to the post that included a user_id field

The user model `has_many :posts`
The Post model `belongs_to :user`

For some reason I cannot connect the user with the post. Am I missing something?

thanks all!

My controller for posts

```
def create

@user = User.find(params[:id])
@post = @user.posts.create(params[:post])


respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Please post the relevant method of the controller where the post is created.

Comment: Updated with post controller

Comment: kindly post the generated migrations code.

Comment: class AddUserIdPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :posts, :user_id:integer
  end
end

Comment: The correct migration should look like `add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer`. Fix it and run `rake db:migrate:redo`

Comment: Yep already fixed that, now it's the creating association program (see below comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need a user to associate a post:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) # or just use current_user as you are using Devise
```

As long as you have `has_many` association you can do the following:

```
@post = @user.posts.build(params[:post]) # to return newly created object without saving it to the database
@post = @user.posts.create(params[:post]) # to create and save record to the database
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply, but I still can't get it to work. My create action for post controller is (stackoverflow won't let me paste code, see update please)

Comment: @user3546559 what does it day in your log? replace create with create! and paste the output of the log

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.user_id: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m

Comment: @user3546559 did you run the migrations? I know it is very basic but no harm in asking

Comment: Yep, posted my migrations in the above comment! But here it is again, class AddUserIdPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :posts, :user_id:integer
  end
end

Comment: Have you run `rake db:migrate`? The error message `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.user_id` says the table was not affected!

Comment: do rake db:rollbacK
change your migration to this:
add_reference :posts, :user, index: true
rake db:migrate

Comment: Should I create a separate answer? don't know how the points system work... :/

Comment: I think it's because I'm using rails 4 because when I try to create a new post it keeps telling me Couldn't find User without an ID for @user = User.find(params[:id])

Comment: Same, it says Couldn't find User without an ID

Comment: well the error message has changed from post has no 'user_id' to 'cant find user without an id'..... can you share your params? I think we are addressing a couple of problems here... not just posts not being created

Comment: I've been messing around with it. My params is now:
 def create
  

  
@post = @user.posts.create(params[:post])

Comment: on top of that I have   @user = User.find(current_user)

Comment: well params as in the whole param list you get in log window, anyways use current_user directly, what you are doing is not correct

Comment: current_user is a devise variable that stores the current sessions user and returns it whenever required.

Comment: 1. Log in 2. Fill the post form and submit 3. PROFIT.

Comment: You have to do in create action: `current_user.posts.create(params[:post])`

Comment: To be able to have `current_user` helper method you have to be logged in, otherwise there will be no any current user.

Comment: LOL lets Skype a group convo to hammer this one out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51540/discussion-between-sergey-kishenin-and-babar)

Comment: Everyone can we list our skypes? LOL

Comment: They shouldn't be able to post without logging in though. So current_user should work right?

Comment: With the @post = current_user.posts.create(params[:post]) , it gives me ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when I try to post

Comment: Fixed it!! I just inserted used strong parameters and inserted (post_params) . Finally! Thanks All!!

Comment: This would work, me and @SergeyKishenin were waiting for you in the chat room though. you are welcome

Comment: one thing more make sure to include method in your before_filter in your controller else a non logged in user can go on to the post creation route and will get an error. just a heads up.